# Lwjgl and OpenGL - glTexCoord2f does not work as expected

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I try to render a 2D animation using openGL and lwjgl.
The image I use is 896x128 pixels, consisting of 7 single frames, each of the size 128x128 pixels.
Now I try to render this image using glTexCoord2f to get the correct part of the texture as shown in https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/Textures#texture-atlases
My code looks like this:

```
float srcX = 128*2;
    float srcY = 0;
    float srcWidth = 128;
    float srcHeight = 128;

    float u = srcX / animation.baseImage().width();
    float v = srcY / animation.baseImage().height();
    float u2 = (srcX + srcWidth) / animation.baseImage().width();
    float v2 = (srcY + srcHeight) / animation.baseImage().height();

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(u, v); // Upper Left
    GL11.glVertex2f(upperLeft.x(), upperLeft.y());

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(u2, v); // Upper Right
    GL11.glVertex2f(upperRight.x(), upperRight.y());

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(u2, v2); // Lower Right
    GL11.glVertex2f(lowerRight.x(), lowerRight.y());

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(u, v2); // Lower Left
    GL11.glVertex2f(lowerLeft.x(), lowerLeft.y());
```

animation.baseImage().width and height() are the sizes of the complete image.
The "2" in srcX = 128*2 is actually the current frame. But my result looks like this:
[image: wrong animation]

Does someone know what is going wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: maybe "srcWidth " isn't 128

Comment: I looked it up. 128 is the width of a single frame.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem:
OpenGL seems to scale the whole texture to the next power of 2, which would be for the height 128, equally to the original image, but for the width 1024. If I do all the calculation for animation.baseImage().width(); instead with 1024 everything looks like expected.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: "OpenGL" doesn't do this. Your texture loader seems to do this. This is a quite common issue with for example "slick". That stuff is just totally outdated - but so is the fixed function pipeline and the immediate mode you are using.